# Can't update model because already exist when editing

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

I'm building a database in Django with bootstrap and I have my form for edit, when I try to modify the values of my form in my edit form I can't because ''the model already exist''

I send the id by here, the delete works and if i try to change the other values works also 'Curso-alumno' is a association class and 'Profesor' is other model

```
             {% if encuestas %}
            <ul>
            {% for c in encuestas %}
            <th>{{ c.Nota }}</th>
            <th>{{ c.Profesor }}</th>
            <th>{{ c.Curso_alumno }}</th>
             <th><a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'encuesta_delete' c.id %}">Eliminar</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'encuesta_edit' c.id %}">Editar</a></th>
               </tr>
               </tr>

                <tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

I tryed to modify my form but is not working.

views.py

```
class encuesta_edit(UpdateView):
    model = Encuesta
    form_class = tfg_EncuestaForm
    template_name = 'encuesta.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('mostrar_encuestas')
```

forms.py

```
class tfg_EncuestaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Encuesta
        fields = ['id', 'Nota', 'Profesor', 'Curso_alumno']

        labels = {
            'id': 'id',
            'Nota': 'Nota',
            'Profesor': 'Profesor',
            'Curso_alumno': 'Curso_alumno',
        }

        widgets = {
            'id': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'Nota': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'Profesor': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'Curso_alumno': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

I want to be able to modify mi field 'Nota' with no errors.

Comment: Whats the error you're getting?

Comment: @DKMDebuguin 'the model already exist''

Comment: Try to use a function based view so you can control what happens. You can always switch to a class based view when your logic is working.